# How to allocate a portion of numbers to an item, using RNG?

Tags: python, random

So my following code sets the x a random number with the help of the randint from random library, and then i loop while is not a specific number and how many times until it finds it.

```
from random import *

x = randint(1, 1000)
i = 1
while (x!=1):
   i = i+1
   x = randint(1, 1000)

print(i)
```

So what i want to do is having a color, lets say red allocated 500 times from 1 to 1000 eg: 1~500 print ("red color") 501~1000 print ("white color")

What approach should i follow?
Thank you!

Comment: Why you don't just use `if else` to see if `i` is between 1 and 500, or between 501 and 1000 ?

Comment: This isn't clear. If 1-500 is red and 501-1000 is white then there is no randomness involved. In any event -- this business about colors seems unrelated to the code that you posted. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `random.choices` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) with the `weights` argument.

For example:
`random.choices(["Red", "White"], weights=[10, 1])`

This meaning Red will be more likely than White.

Note that you can choose between the `weights` argument or the `cum_weights` argument.

> If a weights sequence is specified, selections are made according to the relative weights. Alternatively, if a cum_weights sequence is given, the selections are made according to the cumulative weights (perhaps computed using itertools.accumulate()). For example, the relative weights [10, 5, 30, 5] are equivalent to the cumulative weights [10, 15, 45, 50]. Internally, the relative weights are converted to cumulative weights before making selections, so supplying the cumulative weights saves work.

Comment: yea that actually will work in my situation, this and maybe o work around with if else. Thanks!